# Lightning Outlook integration latency issues

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook, lightning-outlook, lightning-for-outlook

I'm hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction as I'm a bit stuck on how to troubleshoot the current issue I'm facing. I have a group of users that is using the Salesforce add-on for Outlook. They are able to login, however, they are encountering some pretty severe latency issues. When trying to attach an email to a case or even just doing a search for a case or other record, the side panel just locks up. It can be random. Sometimes it works reasonably okay and other times it is so slow you have to logout and log back in to try and resolve. I'm not quite sure this is related to Salesforce and may be an exchange issue. I know enough about mail servers to be dangerous. I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this issue. I've done some looking online and found a few knowledge articles that had some similar type issues that indicated Salesforce was working with Microsoft to resolve, but nothing that was the exact same type of latency issues that is being experienced. We ran some speed tests and the speeds were over 500Mbps so it doesn't appear to be bandwidth related.

Has anyone experienced similar latency issues. What would be some recommended ways to even troubleshoot this issue? I'm at a loss of where to look and how to help resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you using the add-on as is or you added some customization? (technically you can add some custom component to display there).. If you are using it as is then you can try contact SF/Microsoft support.

Comment: Just as is with no customization. I've reached out to Salesforce already and didn't have much luck there. My next step would be to reach out to our group that manages the mail servers, but I don't really have any input for them other than this outlook add-on is locking up, which will likely get push back without anything concrete.

Comment: If it worth something, I did development where  we placed custom LWC inside this add-on, I notice that in some cases it took 1-3 minutes for the side panel to open and load data, but then I removed the LWC and notice the same issue might happened regardless, so it was not related to my customization. We didn't ever solve it, just accepted it.